# Javascript .replace not working with .match words when more than two same words are to be replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot understand why my code is not working when I am about to replace three exact same words. Lets say if an input is "www.facebook.com www.facebook.com wwww.facebook.com"

my output would be this which is not what I want

```
<div class="content" style="font-size:13px;">
<a href="www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a>
<a href="&lt;a href=" www.facebook.com'=""> www.facebook.com</a>'&gt; www.facebook.com www.facebook.com
</div>
```

but if I input lets say "www.facebook.com www.google.com wwww.yahoo.com" I get what I want

```
<div class="content" style="font-size:13px;">
<a href="www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a>
<a href=" www.google.com"> www.google.com</a> 
<a href="wwww.yahoo.com">wwww.yahoo.com</a>
</div>
```

What I am actually trying to do is when a user inputs a link in a text area and submits it. The code will replace the match link with an anchor tag.

This is my .js

```
var wordlink2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
var hyperlink2;

hyperlink2 = content.match(wordlink2);

var $item = $("#ClassroomCommentComment").val();


if (hyperlink2 != null) {
    for (x = 0; x < hyperlink2.length; x++) {
        var site2 = hyperlink2[x].toString();
        var z2 = $item.replace(hyperlink2[x], "<a href='" + site2 + "'>" + site2 + "</a>");
        $item = z2;
    }
}​
```

I am already blown away with this. Can anyone help me with this :(

**just an additional this is my function to be more precise:**

```
function checkSubmit()
    {
        var $item = $("#ClassroomCommentComment").val();
        var $cont = $("#FileFile").val();


        if($item == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //$("#ClassroomCommentComment").css('color', 'white');

            if (hyperlink != null)
            {
                for (x= 0; x<hyperlink.length; x++)
                {

                    var site = hyperlink[x].toString();
                    var z = $item.replace(hyperlink[x],"<a href='" + site + "'>" + site +"</a>" );
                    $item = z;
                }       
            }

            if (hyperlink2 != null)
            {               
                for (x= 0; x<hyperlink2.length; x++)
                {
                    var site2 = hyperlink2[x].toString();
                    var z2 = $item.replace(hyperlink2[x],"<a href='" + site2 + "'>" + site2 +"</a>" );
                    $item = z2;

                }       
            }



            for (x=0; x<=arraycontroller; x++)
            {
                var n = $item.replace(fullnamewp[x],"<a href = 'http://www.classoncloud.org/" + userlink[x] + "'>" + fullnamewp[x] +"</a>" );
                $item = n;
                //$("#ClassroomCommentComment").val(n);
            }

            if (hash != null)   
            {
                for (x= 0; x<hash.length; x++)
                {
                    var new_item = hash[x].toString().substr(1).split("#");
                    var b = $item.replace(hash[x],"<a href='http://www.classoncloud.org/results/" + new_item + "'>" + hash[x] +"</a>" );
                    $item = b;
                }   
            }

            arraycontroller = 0;
            fullnamewp = [];
            userlink = [];


            var classroom_id = $("#ClassroomCommentClassroomId").val();
            var user_id = $("#ClassroomCommentUserId").val();
            var comment = $item;
            var image = "<?php echo $profile_pic; ?>";
            var name = "<?php echo $current_user_name; ?>";




        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: '/learns/classroom/',
        data: "data[ClassroomComment][classroom_id]=" + classroom_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][user_id]=" + user_id + "&data[ClassroomComment][comment]=" + comment,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){



        var parent_id = data;



        $('#comment-list').prepend('<div class="comments">  <a href="'+user_id+'"  class="image"><img src="'+image+'" width="50" height="50">   </a><a href="#" class="wall_delete" id='+parent_id+' style="display: none;"></a>    <div class="name">  <a href="'+user_id+'" class="close">X</a><a href="#" style="font-size:13px;">'+name+'</a><div class="content" style="font-size:13px;">'+comment+'</div> <div class="time"><div class="star-count"></div><a class="my-star" href="#" id='+parent_id+'>myStar .</a><a class="click" href="#">Comment</a> 1 seconds&nbsp;ago </div></div>       <form id="LearnsClassroomForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/learns/classComment"><input type="hidden" name="data[ClassroomComment][parent_id]" action="classroom" value='+parent_id+' id="ClassroomCommentParentId"><input type="hidden" name="data[ClassroomComment][classroom_id]" action="classroom" value="'+classroom_id+'"id="ClassroomCommentClassroomId"><input type="hidden" name="data[ClassroomComment][user_id]" action="classroom" value="'+user_id+'" id="ClassroomCommentUserId"><div class="displaycomment"><textarea name="data[ClassroomComment][comment]" class="textarea" placeholder="Write comment here..." id="ClassroomCommentComment" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 18px;"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="submit" style=" margin-right:7px; margin-top:10px;"> </div> </form></div>');

            }
        }); 


        $("#ClassroomCommentComment").val("");
        $("#ClassroomCommentComment").css('color', 'black');

        $($(this).parent().parent().find("textarea")).css("height","30px");     
        return false;   

        }   

    }
```

Comment: Could we take a look at code that you're using to pass into the function?

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net could be nice

Comment: I already posted it thanks :D

Comment: Is the user submitting one hyperlink at a time?

Comment: yeah in a text area..it fails to add the anchor tag when links are the same eg. www.facebook.com www.facebook.com www.facebook.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than you need to. The `.replace()` method accepts a regex to specify what should be replaced, and if you set the `g` flag on the regex it does a global replace. So you can make the appropriate change to all hyperlinks with a single call to `replace` as follows:

```
var $item = $("#ClassroomCommentComment").val();
$item = $item.replace(/((^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$)))/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
// do something with $item
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7vcZd/1/

There's no need to first use the `.match()` method in order to use the result of that match as the first argument for `.replace()`.

The reason your code was producing the weird output is that you were passing a string as the first parameter to `.replace()` - when you do that it doesn't do a global replacement, it just replaces the first instance. Because you did the same replacement in a loop, the second and subsequent replacements were within the `<a ...` part that you added in the first replacement. If you add a `console.log($item)` statement to the end of the loop you'll see what's happening with each iteration...

Comment: thank you my friend it works!. One thing left is I don't get how the $1 work and where it came from, though I will be able to research on that. console.log($item) I will be using this when debugging some of my codes ^_^

Comment: In a regex-based replacement, `$1` gives the value of the first sub-match (and `$2` gives the second, etc.). In this case I wrapped the whole expression in parentheses so `$1` matches the whole thing. More info in [MDN's `.replace()` doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

The way replace is working in the following line is what is causing problems:

```
$item.replace(hyperlink2[x],"<a href='" + site2 + "'>" + site2 +"</a>" );
```

What this does is it searches in `$item` for the first case of `hyperlink2[x]` and replaces it with the link.

In your example of `www.facebook.com` 3 times, it will always replace the first instance of www.facebook.com with a link.

To break down where the error occurs, lets go through the for loop and see what happens each time to `content`.

**Before entering the for loop**

```
www.facebook.com www.facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

**After first interation of the for loop**

```
<a href='www.facebook.com'>www.facebook.com</a>
www.facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

**After second interation of the for loop**

```
<a href='<a href='www.facebook.com'>www.facebook.com</a>
'>www.facebook.com</a>
www.facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

It does this because it's looking for and replacing the first instance of `www.facebook.com`, but the original string has now changed and that instance is now inside the href=''.

It's better to make a string and return that, rather than using replace.

Like so:

**Javascript**

```
var content = "www.facebook.com www.facebook.com www.facebook.com";

var wordlink2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
var hyperlink2 = content.match(wordlink2);

var returnString = "";

if (hyperlink2 !== null) {
    for (x = 0; x < hyperlink2.length; x++) {
        var site2 = hyperlink2[x].toString();
        returnString += "<a href='" + site2 + "'>" + site2 + "</a>\n";
    }
}

$("#ClassroomCommentComment").text(returnString);
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/RDkcc/1/

Or better yet, nnnnnn's answer looks best.

Answer (score 1):

From the original question I assumed this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/nb6SQ/6/

```
var wordlink2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
var items = $(".content a");
var repval = $("#replacetext").val();

items.each(function(i,el) {
    var item = $(el);
 item.attr("href", item.attr("href").replace(wordlink2, repval));
 item.text(item.text().replace(wordlink2, repval));
});
```